# Could anyone help me in understanding the groovy script below

Tags: regex, groovyscriptengine

I am trying to decode some groovy script. I was able to figure out that it is a regular expression but couldn't figure out what the code is exactly.

```
def dirNumber = this.'Directory Number'
dirNumber?"61" + (dirNumber =~ /0([0-9]+)/)[0][1] + "@":null
```

Answer (score 0):

According to *Regular expression operators* section of https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html, `=~` is the *find operator*, which creates a `java.util.regex.Matcher` for pattern to the right matching them on string to the left.
So, `dirNumber =~ /0([0-9]+)/` is equivalent to
`Pattern.compile("/0([0-9]+)/").matcher(dirNumber)` and evaluates to an instance of `java.util.regex.Matcher`.

Groovy gives you the ability to access matches by index (`[0]` in your code); your regular expression uses *grouping*, so in each match you can access groups by (1-based: 0 denotes the entire pattern) index (`[1]` in your code), too.

So, your code (if `dirNumber` is not `null`) extracts the first group of the first match of the regular expression.

// EDITED

You can get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the first index (`[0]` in your code) is out of the matches' range; when your second index (`[1]` in you code) is of the grous' range, you get a `null` without exception accessing the group through index...

You can test these scenarios with a simplified version of the code above:

```
def dirNumber = "Xxx 15 Xxx 16 Xxx 17"
def matcher = dirNumber =~ /Xxx ([0-9]+)/
println(matcher[0][1]) // 15
println(matcher[0][5]) // null 
println(matcher[5][1]) // IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Is there any chance of Index out of bounds exception to occur? @Pietro Martinelli

Comment: Yes, you can get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the first index (`[0]` in you code) is out of the matches' range; when your second index (`[1]` in you code) is of the grous' range, you get a `null` without exception accessing the group through index... you can test this with a simplified version of the code above:

def dirNumber = "Xxx 15 Xxx 16 Xxx 17"
def matcher = dirNumber =~ /Xxx ([0-9]+)/
println(matcher[0][1]) // 15
println(matcher[0][5]) // null
println(matcher[5][1]) // IndexOutOfBoundsException